# Can't find max and min in my code

Tags: c

I have written two code for max and min. The first is without, the second with an extra function.
The first one works, but for second one minimum is always 1. Why?
What causes the problem?

(1) Code without function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x,n,min=x,max=1,cnt;
    while(1){
        cnt=0;
        printf("how many numbers do you want to enter\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        printf("enter your numbers\n");
        while (cnt!=n){
            scanf("%d",&x);
            cnt++;
            if(x>max)
                max=x;
            if(x<min)
                min=x;
        }
        printf("maximum is:%d\n",max);
        printf("minimum is:%d",min);
        getch();
        system("cls");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(2) Code with function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int maximum(int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n;
    printf("how many numbers do you want to enter\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    maximum(n);
    return 0;
}

//*****************************************

int maximum(int n){
    int i,a,max=1,min=a;
    printf("enter your number\n");

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a);
        if(a>max)
        max=a;
        if(a<min)
        min=a;
    }

    printf("maximum is:%d\n",max);
    printf("minimum is:%d",min);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Try indentation to make the code readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code invokes undefined behavior because the assignment `min=x` in first and `min=a` in second done without initializing `x` and `a`. In this case you may get anything, either expected or unexpected result or segmentation fault or program crash.

To fix this issue you can modify your code as

Code **1.**

```
int x,n,min,max=1,cnt;
while(1){
    cnt=1;
    printf("how many numbers do you want to enter\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("enter your numbers\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    min = x;
    while (cnt!=n){
        scanf("%d",&x); 
    ...
    ...
```

Code **2.**

```
int maximum(int n){
    int i,a,max=1,min;
    printf("enter your number\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    min = a;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a); 
...
...
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code causes undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means, anything could happen.
You have not initialized the variable `a` and you are doing `min=a;`

**C99 section 6.7.8 Initialization:**

```
If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly,
its value is indeterminate.
```

**C99 section 3.18 Un-deﬁned behavior:**

```
Behavior, upon use of a non-portable or erroneous program construct, of erroneous
data, or of indeterminately valued objects, for which this International Standard 
imposes no requirements.
```

This means, compiler is free to do anything. It can crash your program, your program might print JLo pic on your monitor...Etc...

Comment: Because it's undefined behaviour to leave an uninitialized variable. It has nothing to do with the function, nor because it's rained today, it's just random..

Comment: @tom14: Think about proper values to initialise `max` and `min` with.